# Extending Shrinkwrap modifier

Tags: python, modifiers, animation-nodes, sverchok, shrinkwrap

I was wondering for some time now if it is possible to use the **Shrinkwrap modifier** (in combination with other modifiers, i.e. **Normal Edit**) for projecting a mesh onto a surface in shadow-like manner (like shadow from a **Spot Light**).

Currently one can project a mesh onto a plane using **Project** or **Nearest vertex/Surface point** modes.

The first mode works well only for parallel projection along the main world axes. Using it with the mesh normals (face/vertex?) is a disaster.

The other two modes are distance based projections - so no shadow-like.

In the image below I am showing the effect that I want to achieve
- ***projection based on reference point (the spot light) that will wrap the mesh onto the wall, over the shadow (produced by the spot light).***

Any solutions, including python and add-ons, are welcome.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you have to do is ray cast in the direction of the lamp starting from the vertices locations and use the points of intersection as the new vertices locations.

[image: Node Tree]

The foregoing example showed an orthogonal projection, another kind of projection would choose the ray direction based on the vertices locations as follows.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: This is a really useful node tree for modelling.

Comment: Hello Omar! I was expecting that you will be able to give an answer to this problem! Once again amazing solution!

Edit: One more question. I am using AN version of 2.0.4 which I am certain is outdated. Where I can download the AN version you're using? I would like to construct the examples myself.

Comment: @RumenBelev There are test builds for version 2.1 [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.1_testbuilds_2), while this is not the latest version, it contains all of the new features except the new *Spline From Edges node*.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Another great example of how powerful AN is.

It's amazing how Ray Cast node does the heavy lifting here.

I love vector math but "she" doesn't love me back :)

Comment: @RumenBelev It takes time for the love to be mutual :). By the way, if your object is always a plane, you could use the *Intersect Line Plane* node instead of BVH ray casting, will be much faster.

Comment: @OmarAhmad it worked perfect also with Intersect Line Plane node. Such effect would look good on relatively flat surface, so it's a great alternative.

Comment: @OmarEmara do you know if this tech could be used to solve this ask? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264635/render-other-side-of-perspective-scene-without-changing-silhouette